# MongoDB - get datewise/houlty aggregate count of column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have set of documents in my mongoDB collection. I am looking to get datewise aggregate count of document if date range is more than a day and hourly aggregate count for same column if date query is for single day. The data may have documents with same conversationId, hence it is necessary to group with conversationId as well.Below is sample of data for reference

```
   [
   {
      "_id":"c438a671-2391-4b85-815c-ecfcb3d2bb54",
      "status":"INTERNAL_UPDATE",
      "conversationId":"ac44781d-caab-4410-a708-9d6db8480fc3",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"4dc02026-ac06-4eb1-aa59-e385fcce4a36",
      "responseId":"0c00c83d-61c5-4937-846c-2e6a46aae857",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-04T11:40:06.552Z",
      "source":{}
   },
   {
      "_id":"98370ddf-9ff8-4347-bab7-1f7777ab9e9d",
      "status":"NEW",
      "conversationId":"b5dc39d2-56a1-4eb6-a728-cdbe33dca580",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"ba94b839-f795-44f2-aea0-173d26006f14",
      "responseId":"a2b75364-447b-4345-8008-2beccd6cbb34",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-05T11:40:30.897Z",
      "source":{}
   },
   {
      "_id":"db1eae2b-62d9-455c-ab46-dbfc5baf8b67",
      "status":"INTERNAL_UPDATE",
      "conversationId":"b5dc39d2-56a1-4eb6-a728-cdbe33dcb584",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"b83c743b-d36e-4fdd-9c03-21988af47263",
      "responseId":"97198c09-0130-48dc-a225-6d0faeff3116",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-05T11:40:31.418Z",
      "source":{}
   },
   {
      "_id":"12a21495-f857-4f18-a06e-f8ba0b951ade",
      "status":"NEW",
      "conversationId":"8e37c704-add8-4f9f-8e70-d630c24f653b",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"51a48362-545c-4f9f-930b-42e4841fc974",
      "responseId":"4691468b-a43b-41d1-83df-1349fb554bfa",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-06T11:43:58.174Z",
      "source":{}
   },
   {
      "_id":"4afaa735-4618-40cf-8b4f-00ee83b2c3c5",
      "status":"INTERNAL_UPDATE",
      "conversationId":"8e37c704-add8-4f9f-8e70-d630c24f653b",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"7c860126-bf1e-41b2-a7d3-6bcec3e8d5fb",
      "responseId":"09cec9a1-2621-481d-b527-d98b007ef5be",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-06T11:43:58.736Z",
      "source":{}
   },
   {
      "_id":"cf8deeca-2cfd-497e-b92b-03204c84217a",
      "status":"NEW",
      "conversationId":"3c6870b5-88d6-4e21-8629-28137dea3fee",
      "messageIds":[],
      "messageId":"da84e414-2269-4812-8ddd-e2cd6c9be4fd",
      "responseId":"ae1014b2-0cc1-41f0-9990-cf724ed67ab7",
      "conversation":{},
      "message":{},
      "params":{},
      "timestamp":"2021-05-06T13:37:55.060Z",
      "source":{}
   }
]
```

Presently I am able to group by conversationId, but unable to get data aggregated datewise or on hourly basis if date range is on single date.

Below is the query for same

```
db.documentName.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      '$and': [
        {
          timestamp: {
            '$gte': ISODate('2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
            '$lte': ISODate('2021-05-10T23:59:59.999Z')
          }
        },
        { 'source.author': { '$regex': 'user', '$options': 'i' } },
        {},
        {}
      ]
    }
  },
  { '$group': { 
      _id: {'conversationId': '$conversationId'} },
  { '$count': 'document_count' }
])
```

I have tried adding something like, $hour: '$timestamp' with comma separation beside conversationId in $group, but its of no use and is giving error.

The desired result I am trying to get for above data is, something like this

```
    [{"date": "2021-05-04", "doc_count": 1},
    {"date": "2021-05-05", "doc_count": 2},
    {"date": "2021-05-06", "doc_count": 2}]
```

As for 2021-05-05 there are 2 docs with different conversationId, and for 2021-05-06 there are 3 docs in total but 2 documents have same conversationId hence aggregate count for 2021-05-06 is also 2. Hope this clarifies my quesiton.

Comment: The sample documents here does not match the query. There is no single document that is between `ISODate('2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z')` and `ISODate('2022-07-01T23:59:59.999Z')`. Please provide as well your expected output from the sample documents.

Comment: @nimrodserok edited the dates now in aggregation query for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear to me, but it sounds like you want something like this:

The `groupId` is a field to rebuild the date including the hour, or not, according to your condition:

**EDIT**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2021-05-07T23:59:59.999Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      conversationId: 1,
      groupId: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: {$year: "$timestamp"},
          month: {$month: "$timestamp"},
          day: {$dayOfMonth: "$timestamp"},
          hour: {$cond: [
              {$gte: [
                  {$dateDiff: {
                      startDate: ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
                      endDate: ISODate("2021-05-07T23:59:59.999Z"),
                      unit: "day"}}, 1]},
              0,
              {$hour: "$timestamp"}]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id: {conversationId: "$conversationId", groupId: "$groupId"}}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.groupId", doc_count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$project: {date: {$toString: "$_id"}, doc_count: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8E1VAcfSrC3)

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and have added details. Hope now it lets you understand better. 
The above aggregation is only aggregating over same conversationId, but I want the aggregation to happen on date too.
For instance if there are 3 documents with same conversationId (cb234) and another 2 documents with conversationId (rt456), all 5 having same date timestamp of lets say (2021-05-08), then the result should be count = 2 for this date. As there are 2 different conversationIds for 2021-05-08

Comment: Check out the updated answer

Comment: In playground example the results are as expected, but when I am trying same query on my db then I am getting this error message
"message" : "Unrecognized expression '$dateDiff'" :(

Comment: What is your mongoDB version?

Comment: mongo db version 4.2.9 on doing db.version()

Comment: Then use `$subtract` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1g11DLIGO4v)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @nimrodserok, for mongo version 4.2.9 the query would be

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2021-05-07T23:59:59.999Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      conversationId: 1,
      groupId: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          year: {
            $year: "$timestamp"
          },
          month: {
            $month: "$timestamp"
          },
          day: {
            $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp"
          },
          hour: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        $toLong: ISODate("2021-05-07T23:59:59.999Z")
                      },
                      {
                        $toLong: ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  86400000
                ]
              },
              0,
              {
                $hour: "$timestamp"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        conversationId: "$conversationId",
        groupId: "$groupId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.groupId",
      doc_count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      },
      doc_count: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```